# c++ accessed url log

Tags: c++, http, network-programming, winpcap

im now currently developing a standalone c++ program that would list all the access URL in a browser and its corresponding response time....

at this point of time, i can already sniff all out and in going packets. i am using winpcap for this...

retrieved packets were filtered to by only those 'tcp port 80(http) or 443(https)'...
and know i want to read some http headers. the problem i have is that usually ip are fragmented. 
I want to know how to reassemble this and how to have some details about the http..

Note: i want to implement that of WIRESHARK.. in every packet/frame, it has a 
'REASSEMBLED TCP SEGMENT'

any idea or tutorials how i can easily attain this?!..

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do the same thing [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) does to reassemble packets, which means parsing the header of the packets and sequencing them into another buffer.  The worst program logic is probably dealing with missing information; you'll then have to see if it was flagged and retransmitted.

There are a number of RFCs which cover this:  [675](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc675), [793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), [1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) and others.  If looking through those seems overwhelming, maybe back off and look at the *Roadmap RFC*, [rfc 4614](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4614).